# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem

Tags: ооп, action, java

Хочу сделать простой секундомер (у Шилдта использовано Calendar и обработчик засунут в класс с кнопками). Я просмотрел листинг и решил модифицировать его.

Вылетает ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at        Nanotime.main(Nanotime.java:24)"

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Nanotime {

    public static JLabel jlbl;
    public Nanotime() {
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Секундомір");
        jfrm.setBounds(500, 100, 200, 300);
        JButton Startbutton = new JButton("Start");
        JButton Stopbutton = new JButton("Stop");
        Nano_listener NL = new Nano_listener();
        Startbutton.addActionListener(NL);
        Stopbutton.addActionListener(NL);
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel jlbl=new JLabel("Press 'Start'");
        jlbl.setText("Press 'Start'");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { //Ошибка тут
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Nanotime();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Другой файл:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Nano_listener implements ActionListener {
    long l_temp;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) {
            l_temp = System.nanoTime();
            Nanotime.jlbl.setText("Counting...");
        } else {
            long l_result = System.nanoTime() - l_temp;
            Nanotime.jlbl.setText(String.valueOf(l_result));
            l_temp = 0;
            l_result = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу не воспринимать это как выполнение задания за меня, т.к. весь код я написал сам

Comment: у меня твой код компилится

Comment: а все нормально работает?

Comment: конечно нет, NullPointerException, тк ты jbl у тебя null, а ты у него setText() вызываешь

Comment: так ты этот метод и вызываешь, не инициализировав переменную jbl. у тебя на момент выполнения этой строчки jlbl == null.

Comment: А как инициализировать?

Comment: сделать также как и с Startbutton, Stopbutton,..
(и на будущее: почитай правила именования переменных, а то глаза режет)

Comment: Добавил:
JLabel jlbl=new JLabel("Press 'Start'");
та же ошибка

Comment: java.lang.Error - ошибка среды исполнения, проверьте работоспособность jvm, компилятора. Если код рабочий - то переустановите jdk.

Comment: А у вас он компилиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@BubbleGum](/users/8763/bubblegum)](/users/8763/bubblegum), он запускается, ошибок нет, но он не справляется с заявленной функциональностью, мягко говоря, код не рабочий. Но ошибка вызвана не кодом.
Переустановите jdk(советую стабильную 6 версию), и какую-нибудь бесплатную IDE которая минимально простой подстветкой будет показывать на возможные ошибки. И, если собираетесь продвигаться по пути Swing - посоздавайте просто фреймов, кнопочки понакидайте, навестe на них действия... Только потом беритесь за потоки.

Comment: Повторяю вопрос: ЧТО НУЖНО ИСПРАВИТЬ В КОДЕ?

Comment: повторяю ответ:    
java.lang.Error - ошибка среды исполнения, проверьте работоспособность jvm, компилятора. Если код рабочий - то переустановите jdk.Ошибка НЕ СВЯЗАНА с кодом

Comment: Запустил на другой машине, добавил 
jfrm.add(Startbutton);
jfrm.add(Stopbutton);
jfrm.add(jlbl);
jfrm.setVisible(true);

Вылетает туча ошибок(после нажатия кнопки Start)